# How's to use the values of a Matrice on a recursion or a function method?

Tags: java, function, recursion, procedure

I need to make a Sum of the columns of a Matrice, but, I need to use a function or method. I can't make the sum on " public static void main(String[] args)".

I'm reading the values for the matrice, but I'm having troubles to send the values for and static method or a function?

How I can solve this problem?

public class QuadMagico {

```
static int sumcolumns (int S[N]){
    return 0;
}

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    int N;
    Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    N = sc1.nextInt();
    N++;
    int D[][] = new int[N][N];
    for (int i = 1; i < D.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < D.length; j++) {
            D[i][j] = sc1.nextInt();
        }
    }
```

Comment: "I'm having troubles" is not very helpful.  Please post errors

Comment: The size of the matrice is given when the program is running, so, the Java isn't accepting the declaration, as shown above:  

 static int sumcolumns (int S[N] = new int [N]){
        return 0;

The **new Int [N]**

Comment: Why do start your for loops from 1?

Answer (score 0):

All your code should be completely error free, except this line. `static int sumcolumns (int S[N])`

The solution? Remove the N in S[N]. It looks like this. `static int sumcolumns (int S[])` Then, you are free to call the method whenever.